# Raphael.JS + Fill Path With Image

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael

Its the first time I ever used Raphael.js, so please keep that in mind when you look at the mess of a code :)

What I am trying to do:

Create a "moveable" cube (with ofc 6 "faces"). Each face should be filled with a certain image.

Everything works fine so far, but there is one thing that bothers me and I cant find a "fix" for it, but let me first show you the fiddle and the image in question:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWmpz/1/

Image: http://i48.tinypic.com/2u8f79u.jpg

The problem that bothers me is that when you move the cube, you will see that the image moves or somehow scales weird so that the grey border (that is drawn in the image) looks meesed up. Let me show you:

http://i47.tinypic.com/33xzyhd.jpg

http://i46.tinypic.com/2vt6xl5.jpg

I hope you get what I mean by seeing the pictures of the grey border.

My guess would be that it can be resolved by somehow applying `position:fixed` or a fixed `width` / `height`, but I wasnt able to find anything.

Comment: This might be a limitation in Raphael.js—try using an image (for example a photo) that is smaller than one face of the cube. You'll see that the image is just tiled to cover that face of the cube. It seems like there would be a significant amount of work needed to implement this within Raphael.